# Better solution to use any message broker for spark dataframe

Tags: redis, apache-kafka, apache-spark-sql, rabbitmq, pymongo

I'm running an algorithm to tag on a mongo field and based on that i am adding new field to that document. As my collection count is around 1 million therefore updating and insertion is taking so much time.

Sample data:

```
    {id:'a1',content:'some text1'}
    {id:'a2',content:'some text2'}
```

python code:

```py
 docs= db.col.find({})
 for doc in docs:
     out = do_operation(doc['content']) //do_operation is my algorithm
     doc["tag"]=out
     db.col.update(id:doc['id'],$set:{'Tag_flag':TRUE})
     db.col2.insert(doc)
```

Whereas I have used spark dataframes to increase speed but spark dataframes are taking much memory and throws memory error.
(configuration : 4 core and 16gb RAM on a single cluster of hadoop)

```py
df = //loading mongodata to a dataframe
 df1 = df.withColumn('tag',df.content)
 output = []     
 for doc in df.rdd.collect():
    out = do_operation(doc['content'])
    output.append(out)  
 df2 = spark.createDataFrame(output)
 final_df = df1.join(df2, df1._id == df2._id , 'inner')
 //and finally inserting this dataframe into new collection.
```

I need to optimize my sparkcode so that i  can speedup with less memory.

Can I use any message broker like Kafka, RabbitMQ or Reddis in between mongo & spark.

Will it be helpful?

Comment: Sure, you can. How about trying it, and letting us know how it goes?

Comment: If you did use Kafka, let's say, you could first send to Kafka rather than Mongo, then tag the message basically *immeadiately*, and **then** insert into Mongo (or elsewhere)

Comment: @cricket_007 My data is already present in mongo.

Comment: Okay. And how did data get **into** Mongo? Can you put Kafka **in between** that (rewrite your mongo insert code with a Kafka producer)? Otherwise, you can use Debezium for getting it out of Mongo, and into Kafka, if you needed to